# Is the cls keyword equivalent to the class name?

Tags: python, class, methods

Are the following methods always equivalent within a class? In other words, within `MyClass` can I interchangeably use `cls` in a class method and `MyClass` in a static method?

```
class MyClass:

    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
        cls.attribute = "a"

    @staticmethod
    def my_non_class_method():
        MyClass.attribute = "b"
```

Comment: If it needs access to the class, it probably shouldn’t be a static method.

Comment: `cls` is not a keyword at all

Comment: `import keyword; keyword.iskeyword('cls')` → `False`. Both methods accomplish the same thing but the `classmethod` has the advantage of eliminating the need to hardcode the class name into its code.

Comment: @martineau they accomplish the same thing only if you call `my_class_method` on `MyClass` and not a subclass.

Comment: @Ryan:Good point — but that may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @martineau right, which is why there's `@staticmethod`. My point is that `cls.attr` and `MyClass.attr` are not always equivalent, and the goal of `@classmethod` isn't simply to avoid repeating a typename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls` isn't a keyword, just like `self` isn't a keyword.

No, `cls` and `MyClass` aren't interchangeable unless you are positive that `MyClass` doesn't have any subclasses.

The point of a `@classmethod` is to get the right class type if you call it through a subclass. [for example](https://replit.com/@ryanhaining/WobblyClumsyApache)

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls):
        print(f'class is {cls}')

class Sub(Base):
    pass

Sub.f()  # calls Base.f with cls=Sub
```

If you don't need the actual class type, then you can use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) instead.

Comment: Ups, you are right, it's not a keyword.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  Heck, you could use `MyClass` in the class method, too, if you really felt like it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you comment on the edit I just added to the question?

Comment: @user1315621 please don’t start tacking on extra questions once you get an answer.